# Fail get json using jquery in iis server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I maked MVC4 App.
I wrote this for autocomplete.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Search_PartNumber").autocomplete({
            source: function (req, resp) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/AjaxService/AutoCompleteService.svc/GetPartNumberListModel")',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { param1: req.term },
                    success: function (o) { resp(o.d); },
                    error: function (xhr, ts, err) { resp(['']); }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

AjaxService is folder name. forder include two files AutoCompleteService.svc and AutoCompleteService.svc.cs.
AutoCompleteService.svc include a method GetpartNumberListModel and this is working for sql selection.

source.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
public string[] GetPartNumberListModel(string param1)
{
    .....
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

My problem, It is working successfully in visualstudio.
But not working in iis server. It is say can't find "GetPartNumberListModel".

I did testing that i can access that address on web browser.
If i access to "http://localhost:80/AjaxService/AutoCompleteService.svc/GetPartNumberListModel" in my development PC. I can get json file.
But if i access in iis server's for example "http://150:120:110:111:8080/AjaxService/AutoCompleteService.svc/GetPartNumberListModel". I got only can't found 404 err.
But "http://150:120:110:111:8080/AjaxService/AutoCompleteService.svc" is success.

Please give some idea if you know.
If you need more information or can't under stand my English. just comment me.
Thank you!

Comment: I knew one. It is work if i use Anonymous authentication.
But use windows authentication or others. It don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solute using this way.

I need to use Windows authentication.
So I set Windows authentication to all folder of site.
And set anonymous authentication only AjaxService folder.